# how do I write this SUM query in sql

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables

Operators table

```
proportion, name, routeid
```

(proportion hold % value e.g 100 = 100% or 50 = 50% this shows the % of services ran by this operator)

route table

```
routeid, frequency
```

(frequency holds number of trains per hour)

What I need to do now is write a query which will sum up the number of trains per hour by certain operator where name of operator is Arriva. So if arriva runs 100% of certain service 1, and 50% of service 2 it should work that out as well.

What I was thinking it would look something like this psudo code

```
All arriva trains per hour = Frequency * (proportion/100)
Where Operators.name = Arriva
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  select SUM((ot.frequency * rt.proportion)/100.0 )
  from operators_table ot 
    join route_table rt on ot.route_id = rt.route_id
  WHERE ot.name = 'Arriva';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(frequency * proportion/100) total
FROM Operators JOIN Route USING (routeid)
WHERE Operators.name = 'Arriva'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @operator table 
(
operatorid int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
, name nvarchar(64)
, proportion int--(proportion hold % value e.g 100 = 100% or 50 = 50% this shows the % of services ran by this operator)
, routeid int
)


declare @route table
(
    routeid int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    , frequency int --(frequency holds number of trains per hour)
)

--put your insert statements here

select o.operatorid, o.name, sum(r.frequency * (o.proportion/100)) AllTrainsPerHour
from @operator o
left outer join @route r
on o.routeid = r.routeid
where o.name = 'Arriva'
group by o.operatorid, o.name
```